# org.springframework.scheduling.annotation @Async throws server error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In the below code

```
@Async
public void DoAsynOperation(String param) {
                   restTemplate.exchange("URL", HttpMethod.PUT, entity,Object.class, parameters);
}
```

when it is called from any function say

```
@Override
public void callingFunction(String abc) {
    DoAsynOperation(abc);
}
```

I am getting an error like this

> [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
>   processing failed;]
>
> at
>   com.XXXXXXXXX: Error while Doing Async operation
>           at com.XXXXXXXX(MyClass.java:688) ~[classes!/:1.0.1]
>           at com.XXXXXXXX.MyClass$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a88bc29.invoke() ~[classes!/:1.0.1]
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at com.XXXXXXXXX$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$861169fd.inwardMedicine() ~[classes!/:1.0.1]
>           at com.controller.XXXXXXXXXXXXX(MyController.java:147) ~[classes!/:1.0.1]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at com.medlife.auth.MLAuthFilter.doFilter(MLAuthFilter.java:140) ~[ml-auth-filter-1.0.819.jar!/:na]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:141) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]

Any inputs on this?

Comment: An error is being thrown in yoru async task. Keep going down the stack trace that is not the root cause.

Comment: Added the entire stack Trace

Answer (score 0):

you have to allow the servlet configuration

for example

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
          AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(ctx);
            servletContext.addListener(contextLoaderListener);
            ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            servlet.addMapping("/");
            servlet.setAsyncSupported(true); // For Allow Async Calls
            servlet.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");

    }
```

please check you configuration